# SDRAM timing requirements

Tags: arm, datasheet, atmel, timing, sdram

I am interfacing a Micron [MT48H16M32LFCM-75 SDRAM](http://www.micron.com/~/media/Documents/Products/Data%20Sheet/DRAM/Mobile%20DRAM/Low-Power%20DRAM/LPSDR/Y47M_512Mb_mobile_lpsdr_sdram.pdf) with an Atmel [AT91SAM9G20](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc6384.pdf) and I need to verify on paper (as far as possible), that the timing specifications between those two devices are compatible.

However, I have trouble matching some parameters from the Atmel data sheet against the parameters from the Micron SDRAM.

AT91SAM9G20 SDRAM timings:

[image: Atmel SDRAM timings]

MT48H16M32LFCM-75 timings:

[image: Micron SDRAM timings]

I manage to compare CKE, CS, CAS, RAS, DQM, BA, WE and Address setup and hold times (2.0ns and 1.0ns respectively) between the two tables.

What I am unsure about is:

1. What is Data Out Access time (Atmel specs) referring to?
2. What is Data Out change time (Atmel specs) referring to?
3. I don't find any information in the Atmel data sheet regarding the 100/133MHz clock stability / timing to check against the clock requirements of the SDRAM.

Comment: I think you'll have to post excerpts of timing diagrams.  The words themselves are not enough (unless you've been working with those devices recently), but with the pictures more people will be bale to offer help.

Comment: @MartinThompson: I agree, but the Atmel data sheet provides no useful diagrams and there are numerous related diagrams in the Micrel document. However, I added links to the data sheets for quick reference.